# Definition Query for records created in the past 30 days in and SQL SDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, definition-query, datetime

I am stumped as to how to get this to work in ArcMap...

I have records being created ever day, and would like to be able to show records on a map that have been created within the last 2 days based on a date field in our SDE feature class. How can I write a definition query in SQL to do this so that it automatically changes to the current date and then grabs records from the past 2 days? I've looked on the web, but have had no luck finding anything that matches what I need.

The values in our SQL 2012 database for the created_date field are formatted as such:

```
2014-11-04 18:44:09.0000000
```

Comment: Have you researched date functions in SQL Server? This is nearly trivial with a supported datetime, but ungainly slow with string types.

Comment: is this a AGOL Webmap? since the data being displayed is dyanmic you should apply the query at the map level and filter record created within 30 d of current datetime. You can use current date time filters in operations dashboard...

Answer (score 1):

I Found this to work, based on [How to select data from 30 days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645973) I just had to tweak what they provided from a 30 day select to a 1 day select

```
created_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, getdate())
```